# Singleton property couldn't be used in an external class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created a singleton called "GCTurnBasedMatchHelper", which includes the following code in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pick1;
```

In the implementation I have these lines:

```
#import "GCTurnBasedMatchHelper.h"
//Some implementation code in here...
@synthesize pick1;

- (void) pick{
int r = arc4random() % 2;
if (r==0) {
    pick1 =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Askerer"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pick1);
} else {
    pick1 =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Answerer"];
    NSLog(@"%@", pick1);
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of pick1 from another class implementation ViewController.m?
And how can I access other properties from ViewController.m in GCTurnBasedMatchHelper.m?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the properties of your Singleton class from `ViewController.m` by doing something such as this:

```
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] pick1];
```

Assuming, `-sharedInstance` is what the initialization method is for your Singleton, i.e:

```
+(GCTurnBasedMatchHelper*)sharedInstance {

   //Singleton setup here

}
```

The tricker bit, is Accessing properties that're in `ViewController.m` from your Singleton. I'd recommend creating a `Data Source` or `Delegate` for your Singleton that returns your desired properties.

```
   -(NSMutableArray*)viewControllerProperty {

        return self.myViewControllerPropertyArray;

  }
```

Assuming `-viewControllerProperty` is a `Delegate` method for your singleton. In your singleton, you can now access `ViewController` class properties by invoking this from your singleton.

```
[self.delegate viewControllerProperty];
```

Of course, I didn't show creating and or setting the delegate, nor none of the other obvious stuff like @synthesizing. I take it you can figure this out, as it's not in the scope of your question.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'GCTurnBasedMatchHelper' declares the selector 'pick1', any idea? Says ARC error...

Comment: Make sure you `#import "GCTurnBasedMatchHelper.h"` in your `ViewController.h` class.

Comment: your selector should be pick, as thats what you provided in your code. Make sure you know the difference of the selector pick and the @property pick1

Answer (score 1):

First of all you import the file in your View Controller: `#import "GCTurnBasedMatchHelper"` .

Then

```
NSString *string = [[GCTurnBasedHelper sharedHelper] pick1] //accessing the value of pick1
```

Also you have a mistake in your logic. When you mod (%) a number with 1, you will always get 0. You should mod it with 2 instead (assuming you want to have 50% chance of both outcomes).